# Silent install InstallShield setup with license key parameter

Tags: installshield

I do have a setup that I silently install it from a bat file like above: 
MySetup.exe /s /v/qn

The MySetup.exe InstallShield setup UI has 2 options:
- a demo mode install
- a license mode

With my bat file I am able to run installation of my setup only in demo mode.
There is any possibility to do a silent install in a bat file using License?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you asking us how the licensing in your product can be controlled programmatically? That's going to be hard for us to answer.

Comment: Your right, it's about my product licensing stuff. Thanks any way.